# Calling Action Bar causes an error

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities, 1 main which is a blank activity and the second is a Map activity. I am trying to setup a back button on the top navigation bar for the second activity(Map activity) to be able to go to the main one.

I get an exception when I run the following code. Seen similar issue raised but they were blank activities and not map activities. Moreover the suggestions were to change the class I am extending from. I don't get how that would work considering that messes up the default code implementations for a map activity. Please advice.

The error message and my code as follows. I am using Holo Light for the theme.

> Exception:
>
> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void 
>        android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' 
>   on a null object reference

Code on Map Activity

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //ERROR message occurring on these line
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Manifest - Applied the Parent name for the MapActivity

```
<activity
    android:name=".MapsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
```

Comment: have you set a nonactiobar theme for the activity/app?

Comment: @Raghunandan No, I am using Holo.Light.DarkActionBar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the FragmentActivity documentation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

> Note: If you want to implement an activity that includes an action bar, you should instead use the ActionBarActivity class, which is a subclass of this one, so allows you to use Fragment APIs on API level 7 and higher.

Also since you are using the support library it should be

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Comment: ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); Is returning as incompatible types and casting it outputs same error.

Comment: Can you once try to extend from AppCompatActivity instead of FragmentActivity

Comment: I am extending from AppCompatActivity now. Says incompatible. Required Android.app.ActionBar. Found android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Comment: Have you changed the type of the variable actionBar to android.support.v7.app.ActionBar

Answer (score 2):

So, Actionbar is an old way. You can set up Toolbar in your activity which is easy to use and customize.

toolbar_xml.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.toolbar
       android: layout_width="match_parent"
       android: layout_height="78dp" 
       android: id="@+I'd/mtoolbar />
```

And in map activity declare

```
Toolbar mtoolbar =       (Toolbar)findviewbyid(R.id.mtoolbar);
setsupportactionbar(mtoolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_xml.xml /> in your main layout.
```

Sorry if there is any mistake as I wrote it from mobile, comment if any problem.